# Creating python attributes that reference keys or lists

Tags: python, attributes

I need to recreate attributes that would allow the following code to work.

I generally know how to make attributes but do not know how to handle the lists associated here.

```
Foo.Bar["abc"].Property[0].Value=5
```

Comment: This implies you have a class `Foo` which contains a dictionary `Bar` which contains a class object under `abc: myClassObj` which has list under the attribute `Property` with a dictionary as the first element with ` Value: 5` in it.... Why are you trying to do this? This is 1) ugly and 2) looks like javascript hodgepodge.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT how python should work. Please explain what you are trying to do instead of that syntax. That syntax can be achieved but it is horrible (and I cant recommend enough that your shouldn't do this):

```
class SomeOtherClass2:
    Value = 5
class SomeOtherClass:
    Property = [SomeOtherClass2]
class Foo:
    Bar = {
      'abc':SomeOtherClass
    }

print(Foo.Bar['abc'].Property[0].Value) # 5
```

Do you want to use dictionaries and lists? (JSON)

```
Foo = {
  'Bar': {
    'abc': {
      'Property': [
        {
          'Value': 5
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
print(Foo['Bar']['abc']['Property'][0]['Value'])
```